# Is there anyway to get categorical label of a Photo by iOS public API?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, camera

In case some of you don't know this: If you open Photos app in iOS device and search a keyword like "beach", you get all the photos related to the keyword. iOS seems to included a pre-trained model of photo labeling system.

My question is, can I, as an app developer, use this model to get the labels for photo taken with iOS camera? (something like: User takes a photo in my app, I call a public API to retrieve the labels)

I searched the documentation but didn't find anything. Maybe someone has used such an API?

Ignore this since CommonsWare already answer this part:

*And how about Android?*

Comment: Android is an operating system. Android does not have a camera; the behavior of camera *apps* will vary by app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am asking whether any Android API provides the functionality I described. Excuse my English.

Comment: The Android SDK does not have support for what you are seeking.